# Silverstripe 3.4 - Routing is returning page not found

Tags: controller, routes, silverstripe

I am trying to get the last slug in a URL to pass to my controller to use as a parameter for a filter. Unfortunately I get a page not found error all the time.

Example URL: /sectors/category/energy

Routes.yml:

```
---
Name: mysiteroutes
After: framework/routes#coreroutes
---
Director:
  rules:
    'sectors': 'BlogPostsPage_Controller'
```

My controller:

```
class BlogPostsPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

private static $url_handlers = array(
    '$ID' => 'News',
);

private static $allowed_actions = array('News');

public function News(SS_HTTPRequest $request)
{
   $news = BlogPost::get()
        ->filter(array(
        'Categories.URLSegment' => '',
        'Tags.Title' => 'News'
        ))
        ;
    return $this->render();
    }
}
```

Doing a debug shows that ID is energy but that's as far as it gets.

Have I missed something?

Thanks

Comment: Did you `?flush` ? Also https://github.com/NightJar/ssrigging-slug is a nice module you can use for this functionality.

Comment: I don't think you need `framework/routes#coreroutes`, fairly sure you just need `#coreroutes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not define the `Category` part that is in the URL you give. SilverStripe is now looking for a route that fits with `Category/Energy` which it cannot find - because it's not yet defined.

So if `Category` is a variable you could define it in your `$url_handlers` like this

**BlogPostsPage_Controller**

```
private static $url_handlers = array(
    '$Category/$ID' => 'News',
);
```

**OR**

If it isn't a variable you could just set it in your `routes.yml` like this

**routes.yml**

```
'sectors/category': 'BlogPostsPage_Controller'
```

Either way, you should change one of the two files in order to make it work.